# Chrome and firefox wont load css with the html 5 doctype

Tags: css, google-chrome

As soon as i place the  into my script my page shows perfectly in IE but in firefox and chrome it doesn't load my css file at all.

But when i remove the doctype tag both firefox and chrome show the page perfectly!
And the weird thing is when i load the file locally it works fine with the doctype tag..

Is my host out of date or something?

"Solved"it with:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Is your server sending the correct MIME type for CSS files? They need to be text/css or Firefox (etc) will ignore them. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Incorrect_MIME_Type_for_CSS_Files

Answer (score 1):

The solution you found yourself doesn't solve problems, it just puts a bandaid on it by not including a doctype for different browsers which isn't good practice.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a lot of CSS errors and warnings, take a look at this link and work your way through them and maybe it will start working...

http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.chatboxlive.com%2Fchat%2Findex2.php&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en

As for your HTML, you have duplicated some id names which is bad markup, take a look here and try either renaming them or changing it to a class as you can have many classes with the same name...

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.chatboxlive.com%2Fchat%2Findex2.php&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Ahh thats nasty! Thanks ill get on it!

Answer (score 0):

A doctype is required in today's modern web pages. Without one, you are in quirks mode and, IE in particular, will struggle to present your page properly. You never want to be in quirks mode.

Remove your conditional comments and present that doctype to all browsers all the time on all web pages to remain in standards mode. Do NOT use IE as a reference for how things should work.

Write your markup as you think it should be done, validate it, then look to see if it works as you wish in all the browsers. You will have more problems with IE than the others but IE is most likely wrong.